# Number Theory Congruence Modulo

Tags: number-theory

I’m self-studying number theory using George Andrew’s textbook.
I’m at the chapter of congruence modulo. There is one or two parts that I couldn’t quite figure out. Wonder if someone could point things out for me.

By definition, if c≠0, a≡b(mod c) provided that (a-b)/c is an integer. That is c|(a-b).

If a= 5, b=-3, c=8

5 is congruent to -3 modulo 8, 5≡-3(mod 8) since (5-(-3))/8 is an integer of 1.

I read else where that congruence modulo could also be interpreted as the remainder of (a/c) is equal to the remainder of (b/c).

If that’s the case, using the same example. The remainder of (5/8) is 5, while the remainder of (-3/8) is -3. They are not the same.

I think I’m missing a point here. Could someone please help point out where my reasoning is wrong?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is a math question, more appropriate on math.stackexchange.com

Comment: this is my first post. Just realized that I should have posted it on math.stackexchange.com. Will repost it there.

Answer (score 0):

That depends on your definition of the remainder, which in turn depends on a definition of 'integer division'.

It's quite easy for positive numbers: the result of division is the *largest* integer not exceeding the exact result. For example 5/8 = 0. Then the remainder is 5–8*(8/5) = 5–8*0 = 5.

For negative numbers, however, a problem appears with a meaning of 'the largest'. One can assume it is the value largest with respect to its absolute value, i.e. the result is rounded towards zero (some programming languages work this way); then the integer division (–5)/8 results in –0=0, and the remainder is –5.
Or one can take literally the largest value, in which case (–5)/8=–1 and then the remainder is 3.

Answer (score 0):

A quick answer is that when we work with modulo *n* and you are using the following definition:

> two numbers, namely a and b, are congruent modulo *n* <=> a%n = b%n

We have to consider the same criteria in order for them to be equal, and that is, to consider a remainder of the same sign as the divisor.

The long answer involves some group theory in there. It is not easy to sumarize in a few words, but can be simply explained, using the example you have provided along the way.
First, we will consider the group of remainders modulo, that is, a set of posible **positive** remainders when a integer is divided by *n*. Through the perspective of the group, -3 and 5 are the same element, because -3 + 8 = 5.

P.D.: I advise you from reading that book if such definition was given, such vague definitions are misleading and not rigorous in mathematics.
By the way, if you want a good book about number theory I recommend:
H. Rosen, Kenneth, *Elementary Number Theory*, Fifth Edition, Pearson
ISBN-0-321-26314-6